# Customising Azure B2C Login UI

Tags: azure, azure-active-directory, azure-web-app-service, azure-ad-b2c

I've created a simple template like in the demos:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title>Add your title here</title>
</head>
<body>
<h1>My B2C Application</h1>
<div id="api"></div>   <!-- Leave this element empty because Azure AD B2C will insert content here. -->
</body>
</html>
```

This is a file hosted on my App Service at:

```
https://<mydomain>.azurewebsites.net/html.signin.html
```

I've created a B2C tennent and that is all working.  In my Signup Signin policy (`B2C_1_aa-signup-signin`)

I've setup the custom page url to:

```
https://<mydomain>.azurewebsites.net/html.signin.html
```

However, even just clicking on the Signup button on my site returns an error:

> Error. An error occurred while processing your request.
>
> Request ID: |258cfa9e-4dab035257ed702a. Development Mode
>
> Swapping to Development environment will display more detailed
>   information about the error that occurred.
>
> Development environment should not be enabled in deployed
>   applications, as it can result in sensitive information from
>   exceptions being displayed to end users. For local debugging,
>   development environment can be enabled by setting the
>   ASPNETCORE_ENVIRONMENT environment variable to Development, and
>   restarting the application.

I've setup CORS in my .NET Core 2.1 application with:

```
services.AddCors();
```

And:

```
app.UseCors(opt =>
{
    opt.WithOrigins("https://<b2c-tennent-name>.b2clogin.com")
        .AllowAnyHeader()
        .AllowAnyMethod();
});
```

From all I've read, this is all I should have to do. I've been looking to try and find any CORS settings on my web sites App Service but I can't see anything relevant.

My site config is:

```
"AzureAdB2C": {
  "Instance": "https://<b2c-tennent-name>.b2clogin.com/tfp/",
  "ClientId": "<my id>",
  "CallbackPath": "/signin-oidc",
  "Domain": "<b2c-tennent-name>.onmicrosoft.com",
  "SignUpSignInPolicyId": "B2C_1_aa-signup-signin",
  "ResetPasswordPolicyId": "B2C_1_aa-password-reset",
  "EditProfilePolicyId": "B2C_1_aa-profile-edit"
},
```

I've also enabled App Insights on my web app but I can't even seem to get a handle on an error message to solve.

I guess I have two questions.

What should I check configuration wise next?

And how do I find out what the error is? Azure seems completely opaque on this topic. I've no idea of the error at all.

Until I get identify the problem I'm completely shooting in the dark.  As far as I can tell the only way I have deviated from [the docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-gb/azure/active-directory-b2c/customize-ui-overview) is that my html file is hosted on my App Service which from this document is a completely legitimate place to host it.

This [write up](https://csharp.christiannagel.com/2018/08/01/azureadb2c/) describes exactly what I've done yet I my login is completely broken.

After digging around the requests I've found this hidden in an OK 200 response:

```
AADB2C90006: The redirect URI &#39;http://<my-app-service>.azurewebsites.net/signin-oidc&#39; provided in the request is not registered for the client id &#39;b850cee0-f723-47fd-8f2e-c1fa1ec21038&#39;.
```

But you can only register `https` reply URLs so how do I fix this?

Comment: This error page is being displayed by your web application. If you open the network tab in your web browser's developer tools, then the browser redirection from Azure AD B2C to your web application should contain an error message. You can start from there.

Comment: I'e already checked that side of things, everythin is a 200 OK.

Comment: Do you see your customization when trying out the policy via run now? Or do you have the issue with your custom app only?

Comment: I've ditched using B2C altogether. I'm not convinced it's a particularly good product to be honest.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Register your reply url with HTTPS: `https://<my-app-service>.azurewebsites.net/signin-oidc`. Azure app services hosted under the azurewebsites.net domain provide a built-in SSL certificate.